# How do I reinstall Windows 10 and keep all my programs installed?

Tags: windows-10

I have about all my apps on a separate partition. When I reinstall, would it be possible to get my old apps on my new installation without breaking anything?

Answer (score 2):

**(1)** Go to Settings, Update, and then find Recovery.

Do a Reset and then choose the option to **keep all data.**

Works - I have done it.

The only risk is it uses your current profile.

You will have reinstall your Apps but that goes very fast.

**(2)** If you want a new User Profile, **Keep Nothing.** BUT, You need to back everything up first.

I have done this as well

**(3)** Finally, if your machine is running well enough. use a Windows 10 Repair Install and **Keep Everything.** This fixes fewer errors.

Go to the Windows Media Creation Link

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Windows 10/11 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade Button) and select Run. This will launch the Repair.  Proceed normally answering the prompts. The default Keep prompt is to Keep Everything.

I have done this as well.

Comment: I forgot to add, I'm currently using a custom iso and access to the Recovery tab in Settings is prohibited. Any idea what I could do instead?

Comment: All you can do is all in the answer above.  A Repair Install might work for you

Comment: @notd - You made no mention of that fact in your question. You would need a copy of the ISO to perform the actions described in this answer